# Can the word “pester” be used as a noun?

Tags: nouns

I want to know whether the verb *pester* can be used to describe a person.

Can a sentence be made like this:

> Don’t be a pester.

Comment: For your sentence, you'd use "Don't pester me/him/whoever" or "Stop pestering me/him/whoever".

Comment: A Barrel Full of Words: A Treasury of Wordplay
By Jim Wegryn contains: 'Why does a pest pester [rather than] a pester pest?'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For that matter, why doesn't a pest *pestle*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the noun equivalent is simply *pest*.

Comment: _"We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."_ Okay, but the answer just so happened to be very trivial and simple in this case...in fact, OP could have just used a dictionary and gotten the answer to the question.

Comment: Yes, certain questions don't need to be overthought

Comment: As Dan Bron has said, 'Answering [obviously] off-topic questions on the ... site sends the wrong message to the user-base.' OP has included no signs that they have researched either the availability of 'pester' as an agent noun or the possibility of there being a related form. This is general reference; certain questions are unsuitable for the ELU format.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree, the question should be put on hold (though it won't change much, as the OP already has an answer)

Comment: @AleksandrH It changes the way people regard and treat the site. I automatically downvote answers to obviously inappropriate questions, for the same reason, if (a) the answer has been upvoted and/or (b) the answerer has a rep higher than say 3000.